# Misaligned privileges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In asking what I can do for the site, I thought I  might make a grab for the Research Assistant badge. I'm a bit confused because it seems I've earned the privilege to approve tag wiki edits (1500 rep needed, according to my privileges sidebar), but when I edit the tag wiki I'm told that I don't have enough rep; my submission needs to be reviewed. Also, I don't see a Tag Wiki section of my review tab, nor is my own tag wiki edit appearing my my Review/Suggested Edits tab. Should I be able to edit a tag wiki without approval? If not, should the 1500 beta rep for approving tag wiki edits be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit all tag wikis you need the [Trusted User](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) permission obtained with 4k reputation.

At 1500 you can approve tag wiki changes but that is part of the review process and at least a couple people need to approve the same change.

Prior to 4K I believe you can edit the tag wikis of tags which you have significantly participated in but I cannot find a reference to that right now.  Searching.

Edit - search over, [the answer is right on this very page](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/925/40).

Comment: Looks like @ire_and_curses beat you to the details. You were still first, so I'll accept yours to boost that much-coveted meta rep ;)

Comment: @shujaa - looks like between the two of us, you have a complete answer :)  Yay moderators!

Answer (score 2):

Requirements for editing tag wikis are a bit confusing, but basically, there is both a reputation requirement and a specific knowledge requirement. From this answer on [meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83101/132073):

> You will see that 20k users (Trusted users) will be able to edit all
>   tag wikis. Further than that, the ability to edit tag wikis is not
>   connected to your reputation level. The requirement to edit specific a
>   tag wiki is:
>
> ```
> You have at least 100 upvotes in non-community wiki answers with that tag
>     OR you are in the top 20 answerers in this tag
> You have at least 2000 reputation points
> ```

I believe trusted user requirements on beta sites [are lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78033/relaxed-tag-wiki-requirements-on-se-sites) (status completed on that issue), but haven't found the numeric value yet.

Comment: in that case I apologize for all the reviewing you'll have to do if I'm successful in getting that Research Assistant badge.

Comment: Oh, and Trusted User on beta sites is 4k, according to my privileges sidebar.

Comment: @shujaa - No problem. That's what we're here for...

Comment: @shujaa - Also, I'm sure you know this, but [don't cut/paste from Wikipedia](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki). Summarising is fine though.

Comment: @shujaa - your Research Assistant badge is our Reviewer badge :)

Comment: @Ire, don't worry about that.